# Adding multiple results to an array using the IN() operator

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using the IN() operator to fetch multiple data from MySQL in  a single query. But I'm having issues adding the results in to an array.

```
$sql = "SELECT employeeName, sum(emID) as count1 FROM people WHERE dept IN (:department1,:department2,:department3)";
$stmt = $connnect->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':department1'=>"design", ':department2=>"web", ':department3=>"copywriting"));
$rslts = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$cont = $rslts[0]['count1']

if($cont > 0){
    $myArry['em1'] = $rslts[0]["employeeName"];
    $myArry['em2'] = $rslts[1]["employeeName"];
    $myArry['em3'] = $rslts[2]["employeeName"];
 }
```

EDIT:

there was a typo. I've fixed it now.  `if(cont > 0){`

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Aggregate function without `group by` ?

Comment: @Blaatpraat thanks. I'm getting null to `$rslts[1]["employeeName"];` and `$rslts[2]["employeeName"];` also it throws an Undefined offset error.

Comment: Becky good luck with getting explanations for down votes

Comment: $stmt->execute(array(':department1'=>"design", ':department2=>"web", ':department3=>"copywriting")); error is this line 
it should be like this 
$stmt->execute(array(':department1'=>"design", ':department2'=>"web", ':department3'=>"copywriting"));

Comment: @DrewPierce: I really have no clue as to why I can't get this working. Perhaps the down voter may have the answer.

Comment: Sometimes their hands are tied up doing a facepalm

Comment: you missed the $ if($cont > 0){ in this line

Comment: @Ramki that's a typo. I've fixed it.

Comment: Do you really have 3n's in the var $connect $connnect

Comment: See it's not your fault. PHP is god awful

Comment: As @Ramki said you missed a `$` , anyway what if result of `$cont` for row `0` is always `0` you will not get in your statement below...

Comment: @DrewPierce If you're referring to the typo ( `if(cont > 0){` ) that's not actually the error. I've fixed it in my post

Comment: @Becky maybe you wanna do `if (sizeof($rslts) > 0)` instead of `if($cont > 0){`

Comment: @Alex interesting... let me give it a try. thanks.

Comment: @Alex nope, that did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Ok i will put it here Becky

You have nothing called $connnect

Edit:

The [Manual](http://php.net/manual/) is your friend

[`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.execute)

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

[`PDOStatement::errorCode()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.errorcode)
[`PDOStatement::errorInfo()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.errorinfo)

```
if (!$stmt->execute( [what u have] )) 
  throw new Exception('[' . $stmt->errorCode() . ']: ' . $stmt->errorInfo());
```

Comment: ? why not? I do. `$connnect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blah;charset=utf8', 'root', '');`

Comment: Sorry thought your spelling was otherwise flawless!

Comment: what does `Undefined offset: 1` means? It points to this line `$myArry['em2'] = $rslts[1]["employeeName"];` ?

Comment: This is a quick read just jump to the answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684417/adding-data-to-php-variable-with-pdo-fetchallfetch-assoc

Comment: thanks again. It worked when I removed `sum(emID) as count1 ` :)

Comment: then I used a `count($rslts)` to replace `$cont = $rslts[0]['count1']` all good. :) thanks for your time +10

Comment: Anytime. Thx for sharing. Maybe post 10 lines of it as a new Answer so others can benefit

Comment: Who knows. Maybe they can't face seeing a gal master pdo while they get sql injection in mysql_*